# NSUserdefaults not working on iPhone 6

Tags: ios, swift, nsuserdefaults

Here's my problem. In my app I have a tutorial screen and that's controlled by NSUserDefaults, specifically, this line of code

```
let userDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
let hasSeenIntro = userDefaults.boolForKey("hasSeenIntro")
if !hasSeenIntro {
    showIntro()
}
```

This worked perfectly fine until recently. On the iPhone 6 simulator as well as my physical iPhone 6, the tutorial keeps popping up at every app launch. This does not happen on the iPhone 6 plus, iPhone 5 or 4s simulations.

Is there an alternative? I'm at a loss as to why this would only now happen on the iPhone 6 and no other devices.

Below is the showIntro() code. The above code is placed in viewdidload.

```
func showIntro() {


    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Intro", bundle: nil)

    let introViewController = storyboard.instantiateInitialViewController() as! BWWalkthroughViewController

    let page1 = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("page1") as! UIViewController
    introViewController.addViewController(page1)

    let page2 = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("page2") as! UIViewController
    introViewController.addViewController(page2)

    let page3 = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("page3") as! UIViewController
    introViewController.addViewController(page3)

    let page4 = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("page4") as! UIViewController
    introViewController.addViewController(page4)

    let page7 = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("page7") as! UIViewController
    introViewController.addViewController(page7)

    let page5 = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("page5") as! UIViewController
    introViewController.addViewController(page5)

    introViewController.delegate = self
    self.presentViewController(introViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

[image]

Comment: Did you just forget to set hasSeenIntro to true (after showing the tutorial screen)?

Comment: @VladimirKofman Well no, but would that explain why it only replays on iPhone 6's?

Comment: No, it wouldn't; but it would help if you'd edit your post to include the relevant code...

Comment: @VladimirKofman Well, I've added in the only other piece of code relevant.

Comment: Sorry mate, I still don't see where do you set hasSeenIntro to true...

Comment: You should show also where you are setting it to true in your code.

Comment: @VladimirKofman I don't believe I did. I've added in a visual aid to show you guys whats happening.

Comment: But you do realise that you need to set it to true for your logic to work. It works differently on iPhone6 Plus - because it was already set previously (I guess you've just deleted your code accidentally). Try to delete the app from iPhone6 Plus - you'll see you'll get the same behaviour as in iPhone6

Comment: @VladimirKofman probably was the case, I've tweaked with the code a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside `showIntro()` you need to add:

```
let userDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
userDefaults.setBool(true, forKey:"hasSeenIntro")
userDefaults.synchronize()
```

Possibly on some devices you had this code in prior builds, so the bool was already set in user defaults. You could test this by doing a reset on your simulator. On devices that never ran that old code, the intro always pops up.

Comment: Fantastic. I got that code from github and I was tweaking some things, must have deleted this part by accident. Thanks!

Comment: It's even less predictable in that the docs say that `synchronize` is called automatically at "periodic intervals" so, without calling it explicitly, you might see success or failure depending on what the OS did while you were doing something else.

Comment: No need to call synchronize. It will be always immediately available in memory even if it has not been written to disk yet

Comment: Sure, it's normally not needed - but here he's specifically worried about an intro panel, so chances are he'll kill the app quickly after seeing it, and re-launch to test. Possibly killing the app before the auto-synchronize takes effect. Then he'd think he still has a bug :)  So, I decided in this case to include the synchronize call.